# Making JAX RS CXF Interceptors work with WebClient

Tags: cxf, jax-rs, webclient, interceptor

I am having a problem making interceptors fire when using the WebClient class (`org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient`).  In my method that calls a RESTful service I have added an interceptor to execute in the out phase.  I have intentionally provided invalid properties so I can see the interceptor fail, but the method completes successfully.

Here is the code that I am working with:

```
private String callService2(String webServiceUrl) {

    JAXRSClientFactoryBean bean = new JAXRSClientFactoryBean();
    bean.setAddress(webServiceUrl);

    // setup properties
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    properties.put("ws-security.signature.username", "client");
    properties.put("ws-security.signature.properties", 
                   "client_nonexistantfile.properties");

    bean.setProperties(properties);

    XmlSigOutInterceptor sigInterceptor = new XmlSigOutInterceptor();
    bean.getOutInterceptors().add(sigInterceptor);

    // use WebClient (or proxy) as usual
    WebClient wc = bean.createWebClient();
    TestInfoResponse response = wc.accept("application/xml").get(TestInfoResponse.class);
    return response.getContents();
}
```

I am expecting the `XmlSigOutInterceptor` logic to fail because the properties file does not exist, but the method completes successfully.  What am I doing wrong when adding the `XmlSigOutInterceptor`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is my bad.  the XmlSigOutInterceptor does not need to do anything when a get is performed because there is no document to sign.  So the interceptor was firing, it just returned right away.

Sorry for the noise.